# How to Customer invoice to Incoming Shipment

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I want to create incoming shipment from customer invoice refund, when customer want to return products and I will be create credit note for refund.

problem, I can create incoming shipment,which is type equals in and state equals draft
But When i press button confirm. it changes type equals out and move to in delivery orders.

How do i solve it. 
help me please.

code..

```
def _prepare_order_picking(self, cr, uid, order, context=None):
        return {
            'origin': order.number,
            'date': self.date_to_datetime(cr, uid, order.date_invoice, context),
            'type': 'in',
            'move_type': 'direct',
            'partner_id': order.partner_id.id,
            'note': order.comment,
            'invoice_state': 'none',
            'company_id': order.company_id.id,
            'move_lines' : [],
        }

def _prepare_order_line_move(self, cr, uid, order, line, picking_id, context=None):
        warehouse = self.pool.get('stock.warehouse').search(cr, uid,[('company_id','=',order.company_id.id)],context=context)
        location = self.pool.get('stock.warehouse').browse(cr, uid,warehouse[0],context=context)
        location_id = location.lot_stock_id.id
        output_id = location.lot_output_id.id
        return {
                    'name': line.name or '',
                    'picking_id': picking_id,
                    'product_id': line.product_id.id,
                    'product_qty': line.quantity,
                    'product_uom': line.uos_id.id,
                    'product_uos': line.uos_id.id,
                    'date': self.date_to_datetime(cr, uid, order.date_invoice, context),
                    'date_expected': self.date_to_datetime(cr, uid, order.date_due, context),
                    'partner_id': order.partner_id.id,
                    'location_id': location_id,
                    'location_dest_id': output_id,
                    'tracking_id': False,
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'type':'in',
                    'company_id': order.company_id.id,
                    'price_unit': line.price_unit

                }

def create_pickings(self, cr, uid, order, order_lines, picking_id=False, context=None):
        if not picking_id:
            picking_id = self.pool.get('stock.picking').create(cr, uid, self._prepare_order_picking(cr, uid, order, context=context))

        stock_move = self.pool.get('stock.move')
        wf_service = netsvc.LocalService("workflow")
        for order_line in order_lines:
            if not order_line.product_id:
                continue
            if order_line.product_id.type in ('product', 'consu'):
                move = stock_move.create(cr, uid, self._prepare_order_line_move(cr, uid, order, order_line, picking_id, context=context))

        return picking_id
```

Comment: I already show my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For incoming shipments, the source location of the move is supplier location and destination location is stock location. But here you have done the inverse process.from stock location to customer location which is exactly same as delivery order. Change  you source and destination location of stock moves

Comment: Thank you. I will try, you mean field location_id and location_dest_id right??